# Comparing a list of data using three critria and is found match then sum the 4 column of those variable and delete the duplicate valuve

Tags: excel, vba

Hi programmers,
           I have been working in Excel Vba for the last two day for a project. I have done almost everything but i am stuck at only one condition in consolidating the data. the problem is as shown bellow

```
 1st_Name       2nd_name     month     Hours_utilized

 John           smith         jan            10------> Duplicate 1
 Rojer          j             jan            10
 Lucy           burns         jan            15
 John           maccalen      jan            5-------> Duplicate 2
 john           smith         jan            10------> Duplicate 1
 john           maccalen      jan            5 ------> Duplicate 2
 .... And so on Dynamic data
```

So now i need to check this data using the first 3 column. Here in this example John smith and maccalen are duplicate data's. Using VBA i Need the output as such as bellow

1st_Name       2nd_name         month     Hours_utilized

```
 John           smith         jan             20 -------> Like this
 Roger          j             jan             10
 Lucy           burns         jan             15
 John           maccalen      jan             10---------> Like this added and deleted the duplicate having only one occurrence of the data
 ....
```

Here john smith has two entry's so i need to add the hours and delete the duplicate data

If there is a match in 1st row then check the 2nd row and 3rd row if that is a match then i need to add the value in 4th row of the both data and store the data and delete the duplicate

Please Can anyone understand and help me with this can anyone develop a Excel macro for this please. You guys will be saving my life. Thanks in advance

Comment: *develop* - you have not come up with any macros so far. Just concatenate the UCase functions and you'll have unique IDs. Set up a Pivot table and you can catch duplicates.

Comment: Am new to Macro. I dont understand anything u said. I mean i started using this only 2 days ago. I cant exactly pinpoint what or how to do. Please can u help me out with this program?

Comment: Thanks again for your quick replay

Comment: See file [attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-773Ttgo1z6eXZuVWhLUVpoVm8/view?usp=sharing) .

Comment: Yes i saw but i need a macro. I need a VBA program to automate this thing

Comment: This process is one among another 7 processes. I have done all other am just stuck in this. Can u provide me with a Excel VBA program to do this Process as i said in my quesion. I under a deadline

Comment: If you want software development, hire a software developer. We're here to help you with your questions, not to do your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below may work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim intRow1 As Integer
    Dim intRow2 As Integer
    Dim strNameSurname1 As String
    Dim strNameSurname2 As String
    intRow1 = 1 'The first row the data starts
    intRow2 = intRow1 + 1

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Do While .Cells(intRow1, 1).Value <> Empty
            Do While .Cells(intRow2, 1).Value <> Empty
                strNameSurname1 = CStr(.Cells(intRow1, 1).Value) & CStr(.Cells(intRow1, 2).Value)
                strNameSurname2 = CStr(.Cells(intRow2, 1).Value) & CStr(.Cells(intRow2, 2).Value)
                If strNameSurname1 = strNameSurname2 Then
                    .Cells(intRow1, 4).Value = .Cells(intRow1, 4).Value + .Cells(intRow2, 4).Value
                    .Rows(intRow2).Delete
                    intRow2 = intRow2 - 1
                End If
                intRow2 = intRow2 + 1
            Loop
            intRow1 = intRow1 + 1
            intRow2 = intRow1 + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I will check this with master data tomorrow morning and will let you know how it works

Comment: But so far it works great with the sample data that i had. Thanks mate for your help

Comment: `strNameSurname1 = CStr(.Cells(intRow1, 1).Value) & CStr(.Cells(intRow1, 2).Value)
 strNameSurname2 = CStr(.Cells(intRow2, 1).Value) & CStr(.Cells(intRow2, 2).Value)`

Comment: Can You help me understand What this line of code means

Comment: It concatenates the name and surname to make single string to compare if it is the same name+surname. Two strings for comparing.

Comment: If you want to learn how the code works, put a breakpoint at the beginning of the procedure and check the variables by moving cursor on them when step by step running. Use F8 to run step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize **row_start**, **last_row** and **newrow** to the appropriate row index. I haven't done VBA Macros in years so hope that will help.

```
For i = row_start To lastRow
    full_name = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(i, "A") & " " & _
        objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(i, "B")
    For j = row_start To lastRow
        temp_Name = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(j, "A") & " " & _
        objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(j, "B")
        If temp_Name = full_name Then
            hours_utilized = hours_utilized + objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(j, "D") + 0
        End If
    Next j


    objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(newrow, "A").Value = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(i, "A")
    objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(newrow, "B").Value = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(i, "B")
    objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(newrow, "C").Value = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(i, "C")
    objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(newrow, "D").Value = hours_utilized

    hours_utilized = 0
    newrow = newrow + 1

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I havent checked out this code yet. But i will try to develop the code based on your suggesions. Its difficult for me to understand your code thats why its taking time to use it. Thanks mate again for your help....